# Using random forest to estimate a numeric using ranges?

Tags: random-forest, linear-regression

I have a problem where I'm trying to estimate a numeric number given a set of features. The number ranges from 160 to 240.

Could I label the data using ranges i.e. ( 160-165, 166-170, 171-175, etc, etc ) and then use a random forest to classify?

What would be the pros and cons of that vs using a linear regression?

It seems kind of nice because I would have probabilities/confidences with the random forest approach.

Comment: Why not calculate the prediction using any regression algorithm and then add confidence or prediction interval? From my experience, the more classes you have in classification, the smaller the performance.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution to this problem would be to first use some algorithm to perform regression to predict the dependent variable (since the dependent variable is quantitative) and then group these predictions into buckets of the desired width using a loop to iterate over the predicted values.

Example:

The vector of predicted values looks like this:

`(165.9, 163.2, 169.1, 171.7, 178.3)`

If the categories are based on intervals of 5, then 165.9 -> {160 - 165}, ... , 178.3 -> {176 - 180}.

The point is that the grouping of values into categories based on some arbitrary interval occurs separately from the regression. Doing such a thing results in significant information loss regarding the predictions.

Answer (score 0):

Random forests can be used for BOTH classification and regression, so you can use this algorithm directly with your data as is.

You will still have the benefits you quoted, i.e a way to estimate the confidence of the outputted value.